# Receber os valores de array pelo console

Tags: javascript, node.js, aplicação-web

Estou iniciando os estudos em node e resolvi fazer um exercício no qual preciso receber um valor n pelo console do node que será a quantidade de elementos de um array e receber n elementos pelo console do node. 
O problema é que não sei como receber os elementos do array pelo console 
O código que tenho até agora:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var valor = 0;
var valor1 = 0;
var conj = [];

var leitor = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

leitor.question("Digite a quantidade de itens do conjunto: ", 
function(resp,vet){
    valor = resp;
    for(var i = 0; i<valor; i++){
        console.log("Digite o valor de indice "+i);
        valor1 = vet;
        conj.push(valor1);
    }
    console.log(conj);
    leitor.close();
});
```

Comment: **Carlos**, faltou você descrever seu problema ou dúvida!

Comment: eu não sei como receber os elementos de um array pelo console do node, só consigo receber 1 número

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há alguns pequenos problemas no seu código.

Primeiro: A função *callback* do método leitor.question() [recebe apenas um argumento](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_question_query_callback), que é a *string* que o usuário digitou.
Ou seja, ficaria assim:

```
leitor.question("Digite a quantidade de itens do conjunto: ", function(resp){
```

Isso nos leva a um outro problema: Dentro do *for*, teríamos que pedir para digitar um valor pra cada índice, certo? Ou seja:

```
for(var i = 0; i < resp; i++){
    leitor.question('Digite o valor de indice ' + i, (valor) => {
        conj.push(valor); 
    });
}
```

O problema é que o for não espera o usuário digitar e o método leitor.question() se completar. Então, em um caso onde eu quero um conjunto só com três elementos, aconteceria isso:

```
> Digite a quantidade de itens do conjunto: 3
> Digite o valor de indice 0Digite o valor de indice 0Digite o valor de indice 0[]
```

Percebeu?
Uma forma de resolver isso é com uma [função assíncrona](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas). Dei algumas outras melhoradinhas no seu código, mas ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const leitor = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const conj = [];

leitor.question('Digite a quantidade de itens do conjunto: ', async (quantidade) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
        // O await espera pelo retorno da Promise
        await new Promise((resolve) => { 
            leitor.question(`Digite o valor de indice ${i}: `, (valor) => {
                resolve(conj.push(valor)); // A promise resolve e retorna
            });
        });
    }
    leitor.close();
    console.log(conj);
});
```